# Setup Cloudwatch Alarm with Terraform that uses a query-expression

Tags: terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

My goal is to setup an alarm in Cloudwatch via Terraform, that fires when disk_usage is above a certain treshold. The monitored metrics come from a Non-AWS-Server and are collected via CloudWatch Agent.

My first step was to do this manually, by setting up a metric that Selects the maximum disk_usage of all devices on a selected host:

```
SELECT MAX(disk_used_percent) FROM CWAgent WHERE host = 'MY_HOST'
```

I when successfully created an alarm based on this metric. Now I want to do the same thing with Terraform, but I cant figure out how to do that.

If I setup the Terraform-Resource to use a dimension for the host, then I get no results. If I try to setup a metric-query, then I get a conflict between Terraform and AWS, where Terraform tells me that my resource should not declare a "period"-Attribute but AWS demands it and will fail if not provided:

> Error: Updating metric alarm failed: ValidationError: Period must not
> be null

Currently, my resource looks like this:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "disk_usage_alarm" {
  alarm_name                = "Disk usage alarm on MY_HOST"
  alarm_description         = "One or more disks on MY_HOST are over 65% capacity"
  comparison_operator       = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  threshold                 = "65"
  evaluation_periods        = "2"
  datapoints_to_alarm       = "1"
  treat_missing_data        = "missing"
  actions_enabled           = "false"
  insufficient_data_actions = []
  alarm_actions             = []
  ok_actions                = []

  metric_query {
    id          = "q1"
    label       = "Maximum disk_used_percentage for all disks on Host MY_HOST"
    return_data = true
    expression  = "SELECT MAX(disk_used_percent) FROM CWAgent WHERE host = 'MY_HOST'"
  }
}
```

Anyone knows whats wrong here and how to correctly setup this alarm via Terraform?

Comment: Are you sure those keywords can be used in an expression: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html#metric-math-syntax?

Comment: @MarkoE I am not sure. After I was able to setup the alarm manually, I imported it into the Terraform-State to see how the alarm is represented in the tfstate-File. The expression above was the result.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/29398

there is a pull request that should fix this issue:

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/29896